Getting 403 from GCP metadata server
I'm using GCP storage to upload a file and return it's signed/public URL.
I'm getting below error when trying to signUrl after uploading my file to gcp storage.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected Error code 403 trying to get service accounts from Compute Engine metadata: This metadata endpoint is concealed for ?recursive calls

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.getDefaultServiceAccount(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:383)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.getAccount(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:336)
    ... 18 common frames omitted

This is specifically when service-account call goes to gcp metadata.
com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials#getDefaultServiceAccount

HttpResponse response = getMetadataResponse(getServiceAccountsUrl());

My GCP java library version is 1.80.0.
Not able to find this error anywhere.
Let me know if any further details are required here.
EDIT 1:
This is a minimal version of the actual code, gist of what is happening.
int ttlInMinutes = 5;
String objectName = "object-name";
String bucket = "some-bucket";
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
BlobInfo blobinfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucket, objectName)).build();
URL url = storage.signUrl(blobinfo, ttlInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES, withV4Signature());

At this point, I get the mentioned error.

Can you share more piece of code or a minimal reproductible example?
Did you also check which service account is attached to your Compute Engine instance?

@guillaumeblaquiere - I have updated the question with minimal code to provide a gist of what's happening. Currently, don't have any reproducible code with me.

I'm more interested in finding out when the error This metadata endpoint is concealed for ?recursive calls occurs, because I'm not able to find it anywhere in the documentation or google search.

I did find an archived k8s-metadata-proxy repo - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-metadata-proxy/blob/master/metadata/metadata.go. Here, it's specified that if the endpoint has recursive in it's query params, then the request url path must match a whitelisted regex.
Although not sure if I'm looking at the correct code piece that will run on the gcp metadata call (getMetadataServerUrl(DefaultCredentialsProvider.DEFAULT)
+ "/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/?recursive=true";)

Double-check which service account is assigned to the Compute Engine instance. The error indicates that there is no attached service account or you have misconfigured something using the gcloud CLI from a terminal window in the instance. Attach to the instance using SSH. Run this command and post the result in your question gcloud config list. Redact any secrets.

We are using GCE with k8s, where we are deploying pods on GCE servers, and service accounts are linked with server that the pod is deployed on, and not directly with the pod itself.
The issue was that in k8s yaml file, used to deploy the pod, we were not setting hostNetwork. After setting hostNetwork to true the metadata request returned result successfully.
Before this setting, I guess the pod will run in it's own network instead of using the server's network. More info: What is hostNetwork in Kubernetes?
